# send data to method in controller by javascript @Url.Action

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax

Hi i try send data to method in controller

```
 var data = {
  Id: e.row.key.Id
 }
       
 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Show", "Calculations", new {param1 =  data})';
  //here in javascript I have error, near 'data'
```

error

> the name 'data' does not exist in current context

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Show(string data)
```

I tried

```
     window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Show", "Calculations")' +"/"+ data;
```

but in method in  Show(string data) i have null value in 'data'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you'd be able to change to route to accept the id in the route `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, you could just send the id directly, as follows:

```
 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Show", "Calculations")/' + e.row.key.Id;
```

and

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Show(Guid Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

For default route

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Show", "Calculations")' +"?data="+ data;
```

If you are using custom maproute you need an attribute for route. Like this;

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Show/{Id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Show(Guid Id)
```

You can check this
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

As you have parameter name = data at controller level, try below

```
var dataObj = {
  Id: e.row.key.Id
 }
       
 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Show", "Calculations", new {data = dataObj})';

You were missing parameter name in Url.Action. this name has to match as is at both controller and in script file.
```

Comment: the name 'dataObj' does not exist in current context

Comment: window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Show", "Calculations", new {data = e.row.key.Id})';
Try this. 
Either your given info is incomplete or you are missing scope of dataObj.